# viper dynamically loading config file has data race

Tags: go, concurrency, viper-go

I would like to dynamically load config file and not restart my Go app. I wrote the below files, which runs but has data race.

config.go

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify"
    "github.com/spf13/viper"
    "log"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var (
    reloadConfig  = make(chan string)
    reloadConfig2 = make(chan string)
    viperLock1    sync.Mutex
    viperLock2    sync.Mutex
)

func setUpConfig(file string, merge bool, v *viper.Viper) {
    v.AddConfigPath("./")
    v.SetConfigName(file)
    v.SetConfigType("yml")
    if merge {
        err1 := v.MergeInConfig()
        checkForFatalError("fatal error occurred while reading config file!", err1)
    } else {
        err := v.ReadInConfig()
        checkForFatalError("fatal error occurred while reading config file!", err)
    }
    log.Println("Initial config value: ", v.GetString("env"))
}

func loadConfigDynamically(configChannel chan string, viperLock *sync.Mutex, vipe *viper.Viper) {
    viperLock.Lock()
    vipe.OnConfigChange(func(e fsnotify.Event) {
        viperLock.Lock()
        log.Println("config file changed", e.Name)
        environment := vipe.GetString("env")
        configChannel <- environment
        viperLock.Unlock()
    })
    viperLock.Unlock()
    vipe.WatchConfig()
}

func loadMultipleConfigsDynamically() {
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 50)
        vipe2 := viper.New()
        setUpConfig("config_base", false, vipe2)
        loadConfigDynamically(reloadConfig2, &viperLock2, vipe2)

        time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 50)
        vipe1 := viper.New()
        setUpConfig("config", false, vipe1)
        loadConfigDynamically(reloadConfig, &viperLock1, vipe1)
    }()
}
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "os"
    "os/signal"
    "syscall"
)

var reloadConfigNow = make(chan bool)
var reloadConfigAgain = make(chan bool)
var newConfigValue string

func main() {
    loadMultipleConfigsDynamically()
    go printUpdatedValueOnly()
    go justAnotherGoroutine()
    go yetAnotherGoroutine()
    shutdownAppGracefully()
}

func printUpdatedValueOnly()  {
    for {
        select {
        case updatedValue := <-reloadConfig:
            newConfigValue = updatedValue
            log.Println("dynamically loaded config value: ", updatedValue)
            reloadConfigNow <-true
            reloadConfigAgain <-true
        case updatedValue1 := <-reloadConfig2:
            newConfigValue = updatedValue1
            log.Println("dynamically loaded config value: ", updatedValue1)
            reloadConfigNow <-true
            reloadConfigAgain <-true
        default:
        }
    }
}

func justAnotherGoroutine(){
    existingConfigValue := ""
    for {
        select {
        case <-reloadConfigNow:
            existingConfigValue = newConfigValue
            log.Println("justAnotherGoroutine: ", existingConfigValue)
        default:
        }
    }
}

func yetAnotherGoroutine()  {
    existingConfigValue := ""
    for {
        select {
        case <-reloadConfigAgain:
            existingConfigValue = newConfigValue
            log.Println("yetAnotherGoroutine: ", existingConfigValue)
        default:
        }
    }
}

func checkForFatalError(errorMsg string, err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(errorMsg, err)
    }
}

func shutdownAppGracefully() {
    killSignal := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(killSignal, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGHUP, syscall.SIGQUIT)
    k := <-killSignal
    log.Info("OS Interrupt Signal received, application is shutting down!")
    logSystemInterruptType(k)
}

func logSystemInterruptType(osInterrupt os.Signal) {
    switch osInterrupt {
    case syscall.SIGHUP:
        log.Info("SIGHUP")
    case syscall.SIGINT:
        log.Info("SIGINT")
    case syscall.SIGTERM:
        log.Info("SIGTERM")
    case syscall.SIGQUIT:
        log.Info("SIGQUIT")
    default:
        log.Info("Unknown OS Interrupt")
    }
}
```

config.yml

```
env : "LOCAL"
```

config_base.yml

```
env : "dev15"
```

go.mod

```
module reload_config

go 1.16

require (
    github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify v1.4.9
    github.com/spf13/viper v1.8.1
)
```

I learned recently that viper is not thread safe and hence I need to wrap it with mutex. I tried to do the same. In config.go file, func loadConfigDynamically, where I set OnConfigChange is the data race for read. And in the same function at the same line is previous write data race. I run the above package with

```
go run -race reload_config
```

And change the value of env in the config.yml to test if the config file is loading dynamically.This data race only occurs for the very first time config reloading dynamically. For subsequent times, it works just fine.

Comment: If I am not wrong, you want to reload the configuration whenever the config file is modified from outside of your application(either manually or programmatically)? If yes, the recommended approach would be listen for file system events and reload the config on write event. You can explore this module https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify

Comment: I read this recently https://github.com/spf13/viper/issues/378, if anyone knows the solution, please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You lock `viperLock` called `vipe.WatchConfig()` and set `vipe.OnConfigChange`  with a function it is also locking `viperLock`.

Because you already called `vipe.WatchConfig()` and then it started to call `vipe.OnConfigChange` in separate go routine. it is also try to acquire the same lock. That's why there is a race condition.

Call `vipe.WatchConfig()` after setting the `vipe.OnConfigChange` and after release the lock.

It should be corrected as below.

```
func loadConfigDynamically() {
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        viperLock.Lock()
        vipe.OnConfigChange(func(e fsnotify.Event) {
            viperLock.Lock()
            log.Println("config file changed", e.Name)
            environment := vipe.GetString("env")
            reloadConfig <- environment
            viperLock.Unlock()
        })
        viperLock.Unlock()
        vipe.WatchConfig() //this starting call vipe.OnConfigChange
    }()
}
```

Comment: This helped! Thank you!

Comment: It is my pleasure :-)

Comment: Hi Nipuna, now I am trying to load multiple config files dynamically. I have updated the code in the above question. The problem I am now facing is, for config.yml, the update is not printed. For config_base.yml the updated value is getting printed. Could you kindly help me see my mistake here?

Comment: If I use separate viper objects, loading dynamic configs from multiple files works just fine. Is this the recommended solution? Updating the above code for the same.

Comment: Hi @nipuna if I would like to learn from multiple goroutines about the change in the config files, and therefore use the latest values in the application after config files are changes, i am using channels to pass the new value. I have updated the code to do the same. Could you kindly let me know if this is a good approach? Please also advice me if there is a better way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that go thinks that a variable is being modified and accessed by two goroutines at the same time and that there is no lock on the modified and accessed places.
Something like the following example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "time"
)

type Foo struct {
    f func(string)
}

func (f *Foo) Watch() {
    go func() {
        for {
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
            if f.f != nil {
                f.f("hello world")
            }
        }
    }()
}

func (f *Foo) SetF(fun func(string)) {
    f.f = fun
}

func main() {
    f := Foo{}

    f.Watch()
    f.SetF(func(s string) {
    })

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
}
```

It has a data race. If I put the same lock on both the modified and read places there will be no data race:

```golang
package main

import (
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var lock sync.Mutex

type Foo struct {
    f func(string)
}

func (f *Foo) Watch() {
    go func() {
        for {
            time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
            lock.Lock() // read places
            if f.f != nil {
                f.f("hello world")
            }
            lock.Unlock()
        }
    }()
}

func (f *Foo) SetF(fun func(string)) {
    f.f = fun
}

func main() {
    f := Foo{}

    f.Watch()
    lock.Lock() // write places
    f.SetF(func(s string) {
    })
    lock.Unlock()

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
}
```

Or to eliminate the possibility of two goroutines reading and writing at the same time would work fine:

```golang
func main() {
    f := Foo{}

    f.SetF(func(s string) {
    })
    f.Watch()

    time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)
}
```

Comment: thanks for looking into this. Yes, I encountered something similar. A library function I was using internally called another that created conflict. nipuna's suggestion above worked.